# What dragon(s) was Bilbo talking about during his 111th birthday?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In *The Fellowship of the Ring* film during Bilbo's 111th birthday when Merry and Pippin shot off the dragon firework, Bilbo exclaims,

> Nonsense! There hasn't been a dragon in these parts in ages!

What dragon(s) was Bilbo talking about and just how long ago was it exactly? Is any of this actually documented/mentioned elsewhere?

Comment: That should be 111st, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, it’s pronounced “eleventeen*th*”, so I think that’s right.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill it’s “Eleventy first” in the books

Comment: *"Today is my one hundred and eleventh birthday: I am eleventy-one today!"*

Comment: @Edlothiad Confirmed. I stand corrected.

Comment: The full text is [here](https://archive.org/stream/TheLordOfTheRing1TheFellowshipOfTheRing/The+Lord+Of+The+Ring+1-The+Fellowship+Of+The+Ring_djvu.txt). It begins thus:   
`Chapter 1 . A Long-expected Party`   
When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced that he would shortly be celebrating his eleventy-first birthday with a party of special magnificence, there was much talk and excitement in Hobbiton.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given this was an invention for the films the scene must be taken with a pinch of salt. The original occurrence in the book, that firework was let off by Gandalf specifically for Bilbo and signalled the beginning of supper:

> And there was also one last surprise, in honour of Bilbo ... The dragon passed like an express train, turned a somersault, and burst over Bywater with a deafening explosion.
>   ‘That is the signal for supper!’ said Bilbo.
>   <sub>Fellowship of the Ring, Book I, Chapter 1: A Long-Expected Party</sub>

The quote from the films, or anything of the like is never mentioned in the books and the only mention of Dragons in the Shire is "The Green Dragon" inn, the only dragon in Bywater.

From [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63395) we know of only 4 named dragons: Glarung, Ancalagon, Scatha and Smaug. Of those we don't have much reason to believe it was Smaug that was spotted in or around the Shire.

Glarung remained mostly in West Beleriand and would've been unlikely to have been one mentioned by Bilbo, even though he had at times ventured close to the Ered Luin reaching the arms of Gelion.

Ancalagon doesn't have much written about him, although we know he was finally thrown down on Thangorodrim, which again is not near to the Shire.

Finally, Scatha, the most likely culprit, was slain in ca. Third Age 2000 by Fram of the Éothéod; the ancestors of the Rohirrim. Although like the others, Scatha was located around the Grey Mountains and therefore quite far from the Shire.

As such it would seem this was a movie invention, and while there have been many dragons and some may have ventured into or flown over the Shire, there is no mention of them made. As Ted Sandyman says *"There’s only one Dragon in Bywater, and that’s Green"* (ibid, Chapter 2: The Shadow of the Past)

Comment: There were many other lesser dragons, mostly to the North of the Grey Mountains. There may have been some seen in the area of Arnor, especially during the wars with Angmar.

Comment: I'm aware, but it's difficult to say what dragons it was, how long ago and where they'd ventured as very little is known of them. Dragons in the shire isn't actually documented anywhere because it's a liberty the film took.

Comment: "these parts" doesn't even necessarily mean "the Shire". As a scholar of some note Bilbo could be referring to a much larger area. Additionally "ages" could be literal, and it's the First Age dragons he's referring to.

Comment: Sure, these parts don't mean the Shire, but I didn't take them to mean the entirety of Middle-earth in the Third Age, or to include Beleriand, because of the death of Smaug and Scatha hadn't been that long ago. I took it to mean Eriador, and while there were unnamed dragons, we know not what areas they roamed in, and it was certainly not well documented.

Comment: I think the mistake here is to assume that the movies somehow care to follow canon. You may recall that Merry and Pippin didn't have jack to do with the fireworks in the book, so why would this random movie quote by Bilbo be any different?

Answer (score 6):

> What dragon(s) was Bilbo talking about and just how long ago was it exactly?

Nobody knows. This is just a line appearing in the movie, not in the books. There is no canonical evidence what-so-ever that a dragon was ever seen or lived near The Shire.

Everything else is just speculation.